# Chartist dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartist.js

I'm making a website where users can upload data that will be displayed as a graph

HTML:`<div id="data"></div>`

test1.php outputs:`,-0.05,-0.07,-0.07,-0.07,0.14,0.14,0.09,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.65,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.63,0.58,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.56,0.84,0.79,0.77,0.77`

js/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#data").load("test1.php");
    var data = $("#data").text().split(",").slice(1);

    new Chartist.Line(".ct-chart", {

        labels: [data],
        series:[ data ]
        }, {
        fullWidth: true,
        height: 650,
        chartPadding: {
        right: 0
     }

   }); 

});
```

The graph does not show up and I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Exceeded maximum number of iterations while optimizing
>   scale step

But if I type `$("#data").text().split(",").slice(1)` into the console and paste the output into labels and series it works fine it also works if you make data a normal array and don't get the data from the page

Comment: check https://github.com/mfpierre/meteor-chartist-js/issues/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the `$.load` function runs an xhr request. The XHR requests are normally Asynchronous (google the definition of the acronym AJAX) - therefore the data you are trying to input is not present at the time you need it. It is only returned from the php page, after all of the http-request is done - which is most likely after the `Charlist.new()` function has fired.

Look at the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you instead tried something like this (NOT tested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax("test1.php", {
    success:function(response) {
        var data = response.split(",").slice(1);

        new Chartist.Line(".ct-chart", {
                labels: [data],
                series:[ data ]
            }, {
                fullWidth: true,
                height: 650,
                chartPadding: {
                    right: 0
                }
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

EDIT: Ok i updated some code. As i said, This is untested. But this should steer you in the right direction. Try it now. If it doesnt work 100% do some testing and debugging, and maybe you'll learn something..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax.get is not a function remove the "." and it says Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajax is not defined